# Get top most UIViewController if its presented modally

Tags: ios, swift

I have presented a ViewController modally using `vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen`

But when I try to get the top most view controller using the below code, it returns nil.

```
func getTopViewController() -> UIViewController? {
    var topController: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
    while topController?.presentedViewController != nil {
        topController = topController?.presentedViewController
    }
    return topController
}
```

Here `topController?.presentedViewController` returns nil, if I present it using `vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen` and its working fine if I use default presentation style.

Did anyone faced the same issue, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController` it return nil?

Comment: No. topController?.presentedViewController returns nil, even if a vc is presented

Comment: The function will not work (reliably) - because a modally presented view controller can be presented by any other view controller in the vc chain. So, your rootViewController's `presentedViewController` can be nil, while there is actually a view controller in the chain which is presenting another one (not necessarily the one you are after).

Comment: But if I change the presentation style then its working properly

Comment: @christijk Are you using `UITabBarController`?

Comment: christijk, this is exactly what I am saying: this function `getTopViewController()`  does not work reliable. Where the modal presented view controller and it's view is actually linked into the chain depends not only on the presentation style, but also on the size-class, whether there is a vc defining its presentation context, and on the dynamic chain of view controllers. ;) You need a different approach for your problem. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have created this extension for getting topmost controller

```
   extension UIViewController {
    var topMostViewController : UIViewController {
        
        if let presented = self.presentedViewController {
            return presented.topMostViewController
        }
        
        if let navigation = self as? UINavigationController {
            return navigation.visibleViewController?.topMostViewController ?? navigation
        }
        
        if let tab = self as? UITabBarController {
            return tab.selectedViewController?.topMostViewController ?? tab
        }
        return self
    }
}

extension UIApplication {
    var topMostViewController : UIViewController? {
        return self.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.topMostViewController
    }
}
```

Hope this will work for you